# Company profile db with php html

Tags: php, html, sql, forms

so, i would like to create a php complex form that can store details about a company. for each company would like to have multiple tabs where different data will be stored. ex: tab1 company address, tab2: company network setup and so on...
form should be able to input/retrieve data by users/admins

everything trough html/php page url rather then mysql

i`ll appreciate any type of suggestion/help....

note: i would like to add this to an existing os ticketing system as different tab http://osticket.com/

Thank you!

Comment: This question is too broad for SO. Questions here should be about some specific coding issue.

Answer (score 0):

Company details are commonly stored in a database, all data should be stored in a database, where the potentially complex structure of data and relationships between objects can utilise the common but complex sorting / reading / writing methods implemented by mysql, mssql, oracle or other dbms. An example of an exception to this concept is a user's password, which should not be stored as plain text at all.

MySQL should be used for the storage of this data because it seems like the database is already being used, any more sources of data will require middleware like scripts to better synchonize the multiple systems being used.

PHP can write to the file system using [fwrite()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) and the data can be read using [fopen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)

Alternatively you can set up the company section using an API interface to the database, this way the company data may be fetched and delivered through SOAP or HTTP && JSON to be rendered using only HTML / PHP / XLST